# Want to assign only the first key and second key from the hashmap to Long variable xyzId1 and xyzId2

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, iterator, key

```
public static Map<Long, Map<String, String>> xyz1 = new HashMap<Long, 
                                                     Map<String, String>>();
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
   for (Map.Entry<Long, Map<String, String>> entry : xyz1.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + 
        entry.getValue());
        Long xyzId1 = entry.getKey();
        Long xyzId2 = entry.getKey();
}
```

I want to add only the first and second key from the hashmap to the Long variables and want to skip the rest.

Comment: *first and second key from the hashmap* ...first and second based on some ordering? or any first two?

Comment: Did you know that you can simply write `new HashMap<>()` instead of repeating the type arguments?

Comment: @nullpointer I need the first two

Comment: @Holger As in? I am sorry i didn't get you.

Comment: In your example, you have two occurrences of a `HashMap` creation. Each time, repeating the type arguments of the `Map` is obsolete. In the first occurrence, you even had to insert a line break in the middle of the expression due to the superfluous type arguments. Just replace `new HashMap<Long, Map<String, String>>()` with `new HashMap<>()`. Likewise, you can replace `new HashMap<Integer, Integer>()` with `new HashMap<>()`.